# What makes this PowerShell script so slow to read lines in a file?

Tags: powershell

Here is the script I am using, the file passed in is about 500mb

```
$file=$args[0]

If ($args[1] -eq 'response') {
$results = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern "(?<=sent: ).+(?= type)" | Select -Expand Matches | Select -Expand Value
}

If ($args[1] -eq 'blocked') {
$results = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern "(?<=: ).+(?= ->)" | Select -Expand Matches | Select -Expand Value
}

If ($args[1] -eq 'clients') {
$results = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern "(?<=:\d\d ).+(?= \[)" | Select -Expand Matches | Select -Expand Value
}

$results | Group-Object | Select-Object Name,Count | Sort-Object Count -Descending
```

Is there a faster way to get this same data out?  I'm not married to PowerShell by any means.

Comment: You'd probably get better response if you explain what the script is supposed to do (so people don't have to parse the regexes and figure them out).

Comment: Use `Get-Content` with like `-ReadCount 1000` and pipe that to `Select-String`? Are you sure that your bottleneck isn't the last line? The `Group-Object` cmdlet is super useful, but not fast (IMO).

Comment: Agree with @TheMadTechnician about Group-Object being slow. Select-String is also much slower than the -match operator if the objective is just to get a collection of matched values.

Answer (score 1):

I'd trade `select-string` for `Get-Content`, with a `ReadCount` of 1000-5000, then use `-match` as an array operator against the resulting line arrays. Feed the string matches to a hash table accumulator to get the counts.

Not tested.

```
$file=$args[0]
$ht = @{}

If ($args[1] -eq 'response') {
$results = Get-Content $file -ReadCount 1000 |
  foreach-object {
   $_ -match "(?<=sent: ).+(?= type)" |
    ForEach-Object { $ht[$_]++ }
  }
 }

If ($args[1] -eq 'blocked') {
$results = Get-Content $file -ReadCount 1000 |
  foreach-object {
   $_ -match  "(?<=: ).+(?= ->)"|
    ForEach-Object { $ht[$_]++ }
  }
}

If ($args[1] -eq 'clients') {
$results = Get-Content $file -ReadCount 1000 |
  foreach-object {
   $_ -match  "(?<=:\d\d ).+(?= \[)"|
    ForEach-Object { $ht[$_]++ }
  } 
}

$results.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Value -Descending
```